# Redshift copy command recursive scan

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to copy all files under root directory/bucket

Example folder structure:

```
/2016/01/file.json
/2016/02/file.json
/2016/03/file.json
...
```

I've tried with the following command:

```
copy mytable
FROM 's3://mybucket/2016/*'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<>;aws_secret_access_key=<>'
json 's3://mybucket/jsonpaths.json'
```

Answer (score 5):

Specify a **prefix** for the load, and all Amazon S3 objects with that prefix will be loaded (in parallel) into Amazon Redshift.

Examples:

```
copy mytable
FROM 's3://mybucket/2016/'
```

will load all objets stored in: `mybucket/2016/*`

```
copy mytable
FROM 's3://mybucket/2016/02'
```

will load all objets stored in: `mybucket/2016/02/*`

```
copy mytable
FROM 's3://mybucket/2016/1'
```

will load all objets stored in: `mybucket/2016/1*` (eg 10, 11, 12)

Basically, it just makes sure the object **starts** with the given string (including the full path).

This also means that if you have something like `mybucket/wallet` and a `mybucket/walletiventory` it can apply the rule also, so be careful with names when using the COPY command from S3.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a simple as changing the source url to `s3://mybucket/2016/`, no wildcards required.